# Submitting a pull request for original repository?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have cloned a repository (https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-c) into my own repository (https://github.com/rdpoor/JSON-c) and made some changes.  Following the instructions for creating a pull request, I saved it as a branch with tag `rdpoor-elide-op-state`

But I'm missing something fundamental: this shows up as a pull request in my own Github repo, not in https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-c.

How do I submit my branch as a pull request for the original authors at https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly submit a PR to the repository if you're not an owner and just cloned a repository.

For submitting a PR,

1. First **fork the original repository** to your own account. It'll just create a replica of that same repo but in your account.
2. Now make the changes and **push to that forked repository**.
3. Then you'll be able **generate a pull request to oringinal repository** from your forked repository.

Once original author approves that PR, your changes will be merged with original repository.

Comment: The key thing is to be careful when you create the pull request. Look at the destination offered by GitHub and make sure it is set to the "upstream" repo's main branch, not _this_ repo's main branch.

Comment: Turns out my error was that I cloned the original repo rather than forking it.

Answer (score 1):

When you make changes on your forked version, the pull request comes up in your repository itself. To make pull request across forks, you need to open pull requests tab of the original repo, then you'll see the option to create a pull request across fork, you need to click on that.

[image: Picture attached for reference]